# Error Deploying Java Application on Azure on a Free Tier

Tags: azure, spring-boot

I have been following this https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-for-azure/ documentation to deploy a sample application on the Azure. However when I run the command `./mvnw azure-webapp:deploy` it throws me the below error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:0.1.5:deploy
>   (default-cli) on project gs-spring-boot: You tried creating a site in
>   the 'Standard' SKU but your DreamSpark subscription can only create
>   sites in the 'Free' SKU. You can upgrade your subscription to a
>   pay-as-you-go subscription to create sites in any sku.  You can still
>   create free sites with the upgraded subscription: OnError while
>   emitting onNext value: retrofit2.Response.class

Is there a way, or setting that I could change, to deploy a FREE SKU instead of 'Standard' SKU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the `<pricingTier>F1</pricingTier>` in the `<configuration>` section of `<azure-webapp-maven-plugin>` in the `pom.xml` of the project.

**Sample**:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
   <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0</version>
   <configuration>
      <schemaVersion>V2</schemaVersion>
      <resourceGroup>gs-spring-boot-1559091271202-rg</resourceGroup>
      <appName>gs-spring-boot-1559091271202</appName>
      <region>westeurope</region>
      <pricingTier>F1</pricingTier>


     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For more details, see [`<pricingTier>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/maven/azure-webapp-maven-plugin/readme?view=azure-java-stable#azure-webappdeploy) property and [`Configure Maven Plugin for Azure App Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin?view=azure-java-stable#configure-maven-plugin-for-azure-app-service).